# Why does Ruby tend to assign object IDs in descending order?

Tags: ruby, irb, object-identity

I've noticed that objects have their IDs assigned in a counterintuitive fashion. The earlier an object is created, the greater its object ID. I would have thought they would have been assigned in ascending order, rather than the other way around.

For example:

```
obj1 = Object.new
obj2 = Object.new
obj3 = Object.new

p obj1.object_id # => 4806560
p obj2.object_id # => 4806540
p obj3.object_id # => 4806520
```

Why are they assigned in such a way and also why is there a step of 20, rather than 1 in code run by the Ruby interpreter, but a vastly greater difference between object IDs for code run by Ruby's irb?

Comment: `object_id` is just an integer that uniquely identifies an object, any particular order that you think you're seeing is purely an implementation artifact.

Comment: @theTinMan Shaving yaks? No, I'm trying to satisfy a curiosity.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Handwaving over many details, ruby allocates a chunk of the heap to put objects in:

```
1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5
```

Then traverses them in-order and adds them to a linked-list of free objects. This causes them to be in reverse order on the linked-list:

```
freelist → NULL
freelist → 1 → NULL
freelist → 2 → 1 → NULL
freelist → 3 → 2 → 1 → NULL
freelist → 4 → 3 → 2 → 1 → NULL
freelist → 5 → 4 → 3 → 2 → 1 → NULL
```

When allocating an object ruby uses the first item on the linked list:

```
object = freelist
freelist = object.next_free
```

So the freelist now looks like:

```
freelist → 4 → 3 → 2 → 1 → NULL
```

and further allocated objects will appear in reverse order across small allocations.

When ruby needs to allocate a new chunk of heap to store more objects you'll see the object_id jump up then run down again.

Answer (score 2):

The Ruby interpreter is a C program, you are probably looking at the corresponding memory addresses of the objects.

Answer (score 2):

For what it's worth, you can see a totally different progression on different implementations; everyone allocates their objects in a different way, with different-sized buckets.

**MRI 1.9.3**

```
objs = [Object.new, Object.new, Object.new]
objs.each {|o| puts o.object_id}
# 70257700803740
# 70257700803700
# 70257700803680
```

**JRUBY**

```
objs = [Object.new, Object.new, Object.new]
objs.each {|o| puts o.object_id}
# 2048
# 2050
# 2052
```

**RBX**

```
objs = [Object.new, Object.new, Object.new]
objs.each {|o| puts o.object_id}
# 3920
# 3924
# 3928
```

Answer (score 0):

I just ran a log of object ids, and it seemed that although things went in order, garbage collection seemed to make things go the other way every once in a while.I saw jumps from like `20` to `80`, so it seems to be almost random. But with the amount of internal objects that Ruby maintains, object id orders are nothing to be depended on. It could also be that Ruby starts at the top of the local platform's `int` or `short` to allow an easy test for running out (`if(current_id==0) { problem }`). From what i've seen from our various numbers, it seems to be completely different and non determinable. It (almost) looks to me like Ruby might even be using the pointer to the object, because that is guarantied unique, and would explain the huge gaps (20 bytes) between objects. When I look at the value returned by `object_id`, and look at it next to my system's native pointer size (64 bit Intel).

I just ran a test C++ program on that same system that printed out a pointer to an `int`. The pointer (in decimal) was `140734848324996` and the Ruby object id was `70118105405380`. The numbers don't have much in common, but they are both in the same range and look something like pointers.

Of course, if someone would dig into the Ruby source and find out, that would be the definite answer. I'm trying.